# Makefile ifeq: when are they evaluated?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The following is a very simple makefile that does not seem to work properly.

```
TEST=ON

buildbegin:
ifeq ($(TEST),ON)        
    @echo TEST PASSED
else
    @echo TEST FAILED
endif
```

No matter what I set the TEST variable to, my ifeq statement passes.  I always see TEST PASSED.  Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

ok.  my example was not exactly accurate.  What I actually have is this:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

DEFAULT_TARGS:= all  all_debug  
DEBUG_TARGS:= all_debug
ALL_TARGS:= $(DEFAULT_TARGS) $(DEBUG_TARGS)

.PHONY: $(ALL_TARGS)
.PHONY: buildbegin

$(ALL_TARGS): buildbegin

TEST=ON

$(DEBUG_TARGS): TEST=OFF

buildbegin:
    @echo $(TEST)
ifeq ($(TEST),ON)
    @echo PASSED
else
    @echo FAILED
endif
```

Running either make all or make all_debug will result in "PASSED" being printed.  If I echo $(TEST) before the condition, it looks as if my rules are changing the variable, but the ifeq only ever sees whatever the default value is.

Comment: Works for me - `GNU Make 3.82`

Comment: Works here as well - GNU 3.81

Comment: sorry.  My example was flawed.  I posted an edit with a real example

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**make** evaluates conditionals when it reads a makefile (as you know it uses 2 passes), see: [Conditional Parts of Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html). You can simply check this by using **warning** (which is good thing to debug makefiles):

```
buildbegin:
    @echo $(TEST)
$(warning now we reached ifeq TEST=$(TEST))
ifeq ($(TEST),ON)
    @echo PASSED
else
    @echo FAILED
endif
```

You should use shell commands instead and include them in rule:

```
buildbegin:
      @if [ "$(TEST)" = "ON" ]; then echo "PASSED"; else echo "FAILED"; fi
```

Comment: @user1604180 Welcome to SO! If this answer is the right one (and definitely, it is), you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: @kralyk thanks for pointing at this, it should be $(TEST) actually in this case, because we want this to be evaluated by make. But if you need evaluation within shell (not in this example), then yes - you should use $$TEST. But note that every line is executed in own shell process, so in this case you need to evaluate "within one make line before testing"

Answer (score 4):

Here's a cleaner (I think, anyway) way to do what you want:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) TEST=ON buildbegin

all_debug:
    $(MAKE) TEST=OFF buildbegin

buildbegin:
    @echo $(TEST)
ifeq ($(TEST),ON)
    @echo PASSED
else
    @echo FAILED
endif
```

Comment: @pmod Sub-make inherits the environment of the parent Make, so there is no need to replicate variables explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Parameterise the shell command using *make* variables. This avoids recursive make and even the shell (make will fork the command directly and not go via a shell if the command contains no shell metacharacters (<>"&; and the like)).

Something like:

```
result<ON> := PASSED
result<OFF> := FAILED

buildbegin:
    @echo ${result-<${TEST}>}
```

The `<...>` is simply a convention to indicate some sort of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is old, I want to share a simpler way.

It is to use [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html)variable that represents the list of targets.

In your case, a solution maybe:

```
buildbegin:
    @echo $(MAKECMDGOALS)
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),all)
    @echo PASSED
else ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug_all)
    @echo FAILED
endif


debug_all: buildbegin

all: buildbegin
```

Usage: `make debug_all` or `make all`